# Why is my c socket dying?

Tags: android, c, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

I have an Android app that uses pthreads and c sockets.
One thread is always receiving - waiting for data from the server in a while loop.
When the user presses a button the app sends data to the server (JNI call) and the app "knows" what to do according to the answer.
So far so good.
When I added another thread that will send some data every minute the sending upon user pressing the button fails with errno EPERM (not owner).
I have done some testing and it happens only on some devices and after about 40 seconds the socket is "released" and when the user presses it sends the data.

Any advice?

Thanks,
Nir
Edit:
One strange thing is that this bug comes up on some devices (Nexus 4, Galaxy 2 for example).
Another thing that is strange is that this sending from other process is working (user pressing a button is another process). Only this thread with timer is causing problems.

Edit: Source code:
Sending:

```
int send_to_server (char * buff, int len)
{
memset(&server_sockaddr_in, 0, sizeof server_sockaddr_in);
server_sockaddr_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_sockaddr_in.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(get_server_ip());
server_sockaddr_in.sin_port = htons( REMOTE_SIP_PORT );
int ret = sendto(server_sock, buff, len, 0, (SOCKADDR*) &server_sockaddr_in, sizeof(server_sockaddr_in));
return ret;
}
```

Thread function:

```
void * timer_thread_func(void * nothing)
{   
    while ((main_run!=NULL))
    {
        sleep(60);
        //prepare the request
        send_to_server (i_buf, strlen(i_buf));
    }
return NULL;
};
```

Comment: Well, it would be better if you can provide some source code to work upon.

Comment: Exactly which call fails? And how and where do you read and log the `EPERM`? This is not a guessing game!

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the lost reply. It fails on sendto and I read the EPREM by printf errno

Answer (score 0):

Don't blame me if I am wrong but as I can recall:

EPERM  means that no permission to set the scheduling policy and parameters
specified in attr.

Also I don't know if pthreads need sudo(root rights) for opening and taking actions but it seems that you can't open another thread if one is already working (you don't have rights) and you should write your application to have rights to do that.

Comment: The pthread is not opening the socket... I'll edit again to make the question more clear, thanks.